Modularization/Circular Dependency error in android
hello all i am in deadlock please help
i have three module in my android project

1 : App  2 : unityLibrary 3 : bluttooth module

now i want to open the acitivity of App from unityLirbraryModdule
but Unitylibrary is required in app
and blutetooth Module is required in both (app and unityLibraryModule)
so i have added it(bluetoothmodule) in unityLibraryModule and than i have added unityLibraryModule in app but now i want app in unitylibrary module
if i add it then it will throw circular dependency issue
PLEASE HELP

Try to use implicit intent: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters
define an intent action to your activity and then use it to open the activity in the bluetooth module.
